# How to fix "utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss" and add a canonical tag for URLs with the variable "utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console, canonical-link

Please help me. Currently, my website is encountering a Google Search Console (GSC) issue with the message "Page with proper canonical tag replacement." The problematic URL is as follows: domain/cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buCk0.png)

Meanwhile, the URL domain/cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15/ has already been set as the canonical URL pointing to itself. However, for some reason, the URL domain/cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15 does not seem to recognize the canonicalization back to domain/cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15/.

We would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this matter. Thank you.

I've try to add canonical tag to domain/cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15/ but domain/cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15 does not seem to recognize the canonicalization back to domain/cheapest-place-to-buy-iphone-15/.